# Spring @ExceptionHandler not called when controller implements an interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a `@Controller` that implements an interface but the `@ExceptionHandler` methods that are on a abstract `BaseController` are not executed.

I've debugged and it seems the `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver` has this line which tries to find the annotated methods

```
ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler 
    = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, ExceptionHandler.class);
```

But it only ever gets passed the methods  that are on the interface and I have no way of adding the methods to this interface.

Spring does this

```
final Class<?> handlerType = ClassUtils.getUserClass(handler);
```

then uses handlerType when iterating over available methods.

Documentation for `ClassUtils.getUserClass(handler)` -

> Return the user-defined class for the given instance: usually simply
>   the class of the given instance, but the original class in case of a
>   CGLIB-generated subclass.

where handle is actually my controller implamentation class, but ends up with a proxy.

Using Spring 3.2, controllers are registered using context:component-scan. So my question, if it's not immediately obvious, is how do I get Spring to call the exception handler method?

```
interface ControllerInterface {
   String doStuff();
}

@Controller
public class Controller extends BaseController implements ControllerInterface {

  public String doStuff() {
     throw new ServiceException();
  }

}

public class BaseController {

    @ExceptionHandler(ServiceException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ResponseBody
    public Error handleException(ServiceException exp) {

        return new Error(exp.getCode(), exp.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: So, when you get an exception of type `ServiceException`, your handler isn't invoked? It just bubbles up to the `DispatcherServlet`?

Comment: Also, `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver` is deprecated in 3.2. Are you sure that's what's being used?

Comment: Just making sure - You do have enabled annotation-driven/component-scan for this `Controller` class/package?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes to both, i'll try it out with the newer Spring exception handler to see if it makes any difference

Comment: Did you solved this issue with exception handler and base controller?